# Button focus on JQuery Dialog doesn't work when showing from code behind the page - asp.net / c#

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am calling the confirmDialog method from code behind which works fine but for some reasons the focus is not set on the cancel button. Focus is set when i click on the modal gray area outside pop up.

Is there a way to set the default focus on the cancel button without clicking on the page?

**After Dialog is opened**

[image]

**After mouse click on the Gray area;**

[image]

**Here is the code;**

```
 function confirmDialog() {

 $("#dialog-confirm").html("some message here");
 $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
autoOpen: false,
resizable: false,
height: "auto",
width: "auto",
modal: true,
title: 'Warning!',
buttons: {
  "Ok": function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
    return true;
  },
  Cancel: function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
    return false;
  }
},
open: function() {
  $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find("button:contains('Cancel')").focus();
}
});

        return false;
}
```

Comment: Try like this :  `$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").find("button:eq(1)").focus();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use "nth-child(2)" to search the second button in modal:

```
$(this).parent().find('button:nth-child(2)').focus();
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0suq9Lof/1/)

Comment: not working....my code even works in fiddle but not on the browser.

Comment: Do what's browser your is use ?

Comment: Chrome and Edge

Comment: try again please.

Comment: same. may be i need to add timer and set focus after few seconds.

Comment: Great! Anything else to complement the function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225941/discussion-between-renato-santanna-and-user1263981).